# cURL multi for RESTful API

Tags: php, json, rest, api, curl

We are having a RESTful API and RESTful clients, both in PHP. Client connecting to server via cURL http requests.

```
  $handler = curl_init (self::API_ENDPOINT_URI . $resource);
  $options =[
               CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER              => true,
               CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION              => true,
               CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST               => $method,
               CURLOPT_TIMEOUT                     => 6000,
              ];

   curl_setopt_array ($handler, $options);
   $result = curl_exec ($handler);
   curl_close ($handler);
```

Then in model somewhere we call it:

```
$request = json_decode($this->_doRequest('/client/some_id'));
```

There is a JSON response and we parse it. Everything is ok till... Till some users start creating multiple requests and PHP hangs. For example we have a client page which is making ~5 requests to API server. When user opens a 10 tabs in browser with 10 different clients it's ~50 requests which are going one by one. That means that before first tab won't finish his work other tabs won't start their work.

Is it any way to fix this issue in simple way?
We would like to use cURL multi handler for this but not sure how to get responses immediately.

Thanks.

Comment: If your using a php sessions anywhere in the scripts, use session_close() as early as possible to free it for other threads. Besides that, check how many concurrent connections the webserver allows.

Comment: Yes, looks like that it's session problem. But I've add session_write_close just before request and nothing happened. Requests are going one by one.

Comment: Check out http://php.net/curl_multi_init